# Update embedded object inside array inside array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have document like

```
{
    id : 100,
    heros:[
        {
           nickname : "test",
           spells : [
             {spell_id : 61, level : 1},
             {spell_id : 1, level : 2}
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't `$set` spell's `level : 3` with `spell_id : 1` inside `spells` that inside `heros` with nickname "test. I tried this query:

```
db.test.update({"heros.nickname":"test", "heros.spells.spell_id":1}, 
{$set:{"heros.spells.$.level":3}});
```

Errror i see is

> can't append to array using string field name [spells]
>   Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only use the `$` positional operator for single-level arrays. In your case, you have a nested array (`heros` is an array, and within that each hero has a `spells` array).

If you know the indexes of the arrays, you can use explicit indexes when doing an update, like:

```
> db.test.update({"heros.nickname":"test", "heros.spells.spell_id":1}, {$set:{"heros.0.spells.1.level":3}});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
db.test.find({"heros.nickname":"test"}).forEach(function(x) {  
    bool match = false;
    for (i=0 ; i< x.heros[0].spells.length ; i++) {
        if (x.heros[0].spells[i].spell_id == 1) 
        {
            x.heros[0].spells[i].level = 3;
            match = true;
        }
    }
    if (match === true) db.test.update( { id: x.id }, x );
});
```

Apparently someone opened a ticket to add the ability to put a function inside the update clause, but it hasn't been addressed yet:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I think in x will be all document isn't it?

Comment: @DenisErmolin oops ... yeah, that was wrong.  I took another shot at it (see update).  **x** is the document, right, so I'm thinking you should be able to update it by the **id** property.

Comment: x.spells reference to spells but spells in heros array

Comment: It does work well for my, only need to change the variable from: 
bool match = false   to $match = false,  then use $match to reference.

Comment: @McGarnagle but this code will not be atomic as between find and update, suppose you find spell_id == 1, at index 1 and at the same time some other query added/removed embedded document at index 1,  now what will happen is when your query will update in mongo, then it will put updated value at index 1, which will overwrite the document which got added/removed previously at index 1.