# Meteor Approach to Collections Considering Join Aren't Supported by Core Yet?

Tags: meteor

I'm creating my main project functionality right now so it's kind of a big decision to make in my project, I want efficient & scalable solution. I use different API's to fetch users products ultimately for **1 collection** to display products information inside a table with possible merge by `SKU` `TITLE` from different sources.

I have thought of 2 approaches (In both approaches we add `Meteor.userId()` to collection insert so each users has it's own products:

1) to create each API it's own collection and fetch the products to it, after or in middle of the API query where I insert it to `sourceXProducts` also add the logic of merge products by `sku` and add it to main `usersProducts` Only the fields I need, and we have the collection of the `sourceXproducts` if we ever need anything we didn't really include to main `usersProducts` we can query it and get it so we basically keep all the information possible (because it can come handy)

```
source1Products = new Meteor.Collection('source1Products');
source2Products = new Meteor.Collection('source2Products'); 
usersProducts = new Meteor.Collection('usersProducts');
```

Pros: Honestly I'm not sure, It makes it organized also the way I learned Meteor it seems to be used  a lot.

Cons: Meteor collection joins is not supported in core yet, So I have to use a meteor package such as: `meteor-publish-composite` which seems good but this way might hit performance

2) Create 1 collection and just insert everything the API resonse has and additional `apiSource` field so we can choose products from X user X api.

```
usersProducts = new Meteor.Collection('usersProducts');
```

Pros: No joins, possibly better performance

Cons: Not organized, It can become a large collection maybe it's not good for mongodb

3) Your ideas? :)

Comment: Joins do not really hit performance, when you execute them on the client (More: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/). Or you could denormalize and put the products of each user as an array in Meteor.users.profile.products.

Comment: @DanielBudick this blog post is everywhere I have read it many times, It says client side joins: "it’s not the most efficient technique." also it will mean I have to publish 3 collections and many usless fields and not 1 It's huge performance hit I understand denormalize but I don't really get how to do it? It's possible to do with 2 separate collections or It's basically my options 2 where you insert it into 1 collection with 2 extra fields userid/apisource?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should improve the question. You do not tell us anything precise about your schema. What are the entities you have and what type of relations are there and what type of joins do you think you will be doing. How often you will be doing them?

Second, you should rethink your schema and think in the terms of a non-relational database. I see many people coming from SQL world and then they simply design their schema in the same way. Wrong. MongoDB is not SQL and things you learned there you should not try to just reuse here. You should start using features like subdocuments and arrays which can help you solve many basic things you would do in SQL with joins. So, knowing your schema would help us help you design the schema. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096877/how-to-force-meteor-to-reload-subscriptions/26110879#26110879) and especially the comments for the discussion for a similar type of question you are asking here.

Third, have you evaluated [various solutions which exist out there](https://hackpad.com/Meteor-reactive-join-publication-packages-MpSFfsZrMxa)? There are many, but you have not shown us that you tried any of them and how it worked for you. What were pros and cons of them, for you and your project?

Fourth, if you are lazy to evaluate, you can just use [peerlibrary:peerdb](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-peerdb) and [peerlibrary:related](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-related). They are simply perfect. You should trust me. I am their author.

Comment: 1) I don't have any schema so that's why I kinda wanna keep all the information I'm receiving from the API's and in my table collection I will publish the fields I need. Joins will be done always every time when using the table I need to show all sources at my table. 2) considering this I should make 1 collection with array for same products from different sources and single products from different sources. I definitely checked solutions that exists I'm not lazy just don't have much experience to understand it all in one swipe, I guess i basically asked what my schema should look like