# Meteor: Update object nested two arrays deep

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I have a collection with a key called `fields`, which is an array of JSON objects. Those objects can have `options` which is another array of JSON objects. I’m trying to update one of the options by `optionId`. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
Projects.update({
  'fields.options._id': optionId
}, {
  $set: {
    `fields.$.options.$.title`: title
  }
}
```

This does find the correct Project document, but doesn't update it.

Comment: Would you show a sample document in the collection?

Comment: If you need to reach that deep into a document to change something, you should probably re-think your schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$` operator for single level arrays only. Use of `array1.$.array2.$.key` is not supported.

However, if you are aware of the exact index of the element to be updated within the array, you can update like so:

```
Projects.update({
  'fields.options._id': optionId
}, {
  $set: {
    `fields.0.options.1.title`: title
  }
}
```

This is one way to update:

```
Projects.find({"fields.options._id":optionId}).forEach(function(record) {  
    var match = false;
    // iterate fields array
    for(var i=0; i< record.fields.length; i++){
      // iterate options array 
      for(var j=0; j<record.fields[i].options.length; j++){

        if(record.fields[i].options[j]._id == optionsID){
           record.fields[i].options[j].title = title;
           match = true;
           // break;
       }

      }
    }


    if (match === true) Projects.update( { 'fields.options._id': optionId }, record );

});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465849/update-embedded-object-inside-array-inside-array-in-mongodb)